# LU Decomposition simplification on a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If I have a tridiagonal matrix that looks like Tn = diag[1, 3, 1], I can do LU Decomposition of it using n - 1 multiplications (by omitting multiplications with 1) but not n - 1 divisions, right? In this case LU Decomposition is of a single matrix, so I think it defaults to simply Gaussian elimination. Am I correct?

[Example of Tridiagonal matrix form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tCbe.png)

Comment: You meant that the diagonal only consists of $3$'s and the $\pm1$ off diagonals of $1$'s, do you? In that case, the matrix is symmetric and positive definite. So you don't need pivoting and $U = DL^T$ for a suitable diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: Yes, the main diagonal with 3's, and the diagonal above it with 1's, and the diagonal below it with 1's. I've added a link to the tridiagonal form I am referring to.